# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token while running this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> Hi im trying getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when i click on the edit or delete button could someone tell me whats the problem with this code! i looked for 3 hours starring at this code and everything looks fine to me! if you could point out the obvious it would just save my day thanks!

```js
for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                $("#table").append("<tr> <td> " + response.data[i].user_email + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_number + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_address + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_date + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].booking_message + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].request_date + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_1 + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_2 + " </td> <td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_3 + " </td> <td> <button onclick='edit(" + response.data[i].user_email + ");'> Edit </button> <br>    <button onclick='delete_(" + response.data[i].user_email + ");'> Delete </button> </td> </tr>");
              }
                    
                    
                    //to delete

delete_ = function(user_email) {
  alert("inside delete");
};

  //to edit

edit = function(user_email) {
  alert("inside edit");
};
```

Comment: Attach the event handler properly using Javascript instead of using an inline attribute and it'll probably be a lot easier to manage.

Comment: @CertainPerformance could you spare me a min and give an example please! im a newbie

Comment: Could you provide me the response data?

Comment: because the string inside the onclick is not quoted. It looks like `onclick="delete_(foo@example.com)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're adding html elements dynamically and they aren't accessible in the dom when the page is first loaded, I think you could attach your events like this;

```
//to delete
$(document).on("click", ".delete-btn", function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});

//to edit
$(document).on("click", ".edit-btn", function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Here's a working sample. I added the appropriate classes to their respective buttons and placed the data inside the value attribute. Do run the snippet;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var response = {
    data: [{
      booking_number: "test A",
      user_email: "test A",
      booking_address: "test A"
    }]
  };

  for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
    $("#table tbody").append("<tr>" +
      "<td>" + response.data[i].user_email + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + response.data[i].booking_number + "</td>" +
      "<td> " + response.data[i].booking_address + " </td>" +
      "<td> " + response.data[i].booking_date + " </td>" +
      "<td> " + response.data[i].booking_message + " </td>" +
      "<td> " + response.data[i].request_date + " </td>" +
      "<td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_1 + " </td>" +
      "<td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_2 + " </td>" +
      "<td> " + response.data[i].chosen_emails_3 + " </td>" +
      "<td> <button class='edit-btn' value='" + response.data[i].user_email + "'>Edit</button><button class='delete-btn' value='" + response.data[i].user_email + "'> Delete </button></td>" +
      "</tr>");
  }


  //to delete
  $(document).on("click", ".delete-btn", function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });

  //to edit
  $(document).on("click", ".edit-btn", function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
})
```

```css
#table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#table tr td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
}

#table tr td button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that when you generate your html the result is

```
<button onclick='edit(test@gmail.com);'>
```

and the text inside the function should be inside quotes like this

```
<button onclick='edit("test@gmail.com");'>
```

to solve this use

```
"<button onclick=delete_('" + response.data[i].user_email + "');>"
```

instead of

```
"<button onclick='delete_(" + response.data[i].user_email + ");'>
```

in both buttons when you concatenate the strings

Comment: So how does the OP fix it in their code?